# Argument of type '(_: string, key: any, value: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(substring: string, ...args: any[]) => string'

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to get the query parameters in typescript.
What am I doing wrong?

**Code:**

```
private getQueryParameters(): any {
    let queryParameters = location.search.slice(1),
        params = {};

    let re = /([^=]*)=([^&]*)&*/g;

    queryParameters.replace(re, function (_, key, value) {
        params[key] = value;
    });

    return params;
}
```

Comment: The replacement callback function should return a `string`. Yours doesn't care about replacement. You should use [`String.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't want to replace anything in `queryParameters`. This is why `String.replace()` is not the most appropriate method to use.

The best way to parse `location.search` is explained in its [documentation page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/search):

> Modern browsers provide [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) and [`URL.searchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams) to make it easy to parse out the parameters from the querystring.

Your code should check if they are provided by the browser and use them. However, if they are not available, the parsing of the query string can be done by calling [`Regexp.exec()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) repeatedly until it returns `null`, as explained in its documentation:

```
private getQueryParameters(): any {
    let queryParameters = location.search.slice(1),
        params = {};

    let re = /([^=]*)=([^&]*)&*/g;
    let match;
    while (match = re.exec(queryParameters)) {
        params[match[1]] = match[2];
    }

    return params;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the interest. I think there is a typo, `Cannot find match`

Comment: I forgot to declare `match` (I fixed it now). Without the declaration it still works as JavaScript but it creates `match` as a global variable (and we don't want it). The TypeScript compiler complains, indeed (and this is a good thing because it prevents us this way to pollute the global context).

Answer (score 1):

You are invoking `replace` incorrectly, and anyway, why are you using `replace` for that? You should just use `exec`:

```
while(const match = re.exec(queryParameters)) {
    params[match[1]] = match[2];
}
```

EDITED. This way is much better

Comment: Yeah, I was considering this as well, but instead of easily getting the groups straight from the regex you have to split the string again..

Comment: Yes, with the other method is somewhat easier, but it just nags me a bit that use of `replace` when you're not replacing anything... It seems like the kind of hack that, in six months time, no one will know what it does :-)

Comment: Just remembered that  matches hold the groups, too, so  I edited the answer, now it's much nicer